# After making the payment, PayPal did not return the transactionId and profileId

Tags: paypal

After making the payment, PayPal did not return the transactionId and profileId, which further makes it impossible to activate the subscription and also the future charge. I save rawObject too.

shortened view where data is stored in my mongo collection:

```
price: 9999,
message: 'Approved',
transactionId: null,
paymentSystem: 'paypal',
status: 'subscribe',
currency: 'CAD',
invoice: 'MY_GENERATED_INVOICE_CODE',
rawData: {
    result: '0',
    secureToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secureTokenId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    respMsg: 'Approved',
    profileId: null,
    rpref: null,
    endpoint: 'https://payflowlink.paypal.com'
}
```

Why doesn't PayPal sometimes (not always) return profileId and transactionId?

Is there a way, having the data above, to get information about the profileId in order to be able to work with the subscription in the future?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: With that data, no. Where are you getting that data from? A postback? It looks incomplete. You could try adding a silent post listener URL in the Payflow service settings, if you aren't using one; this is similar to IPN. Is there a particular reason you're integrating Payflow Link and not something more modern like https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/  or the Braintree gateway (if you need one like Payflow is) ?

Comment: I am one developer on this project. I have never worked with payment systems, so I got the task to understand this problem. I looked through the code, read it, found the cause of the failures, asked a question. From your answer, I understand that it is better to implement the JS SDK?

Comment: The JS SDK and/or current REST subscription APIs are roughly 15 years newer than Payflow, so yes I would suggest them instead. Or Braintree if you need a full gateway account

Comment: Payflow should just be avoided unless you're maintaining existing/legacy systems that can't be upgraded yet

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will explain to the customer that it is better to change the system, since this one gives a large number of failures

Comment: I have already worked with various APIs, but for the most part they were integrations of third-party resources. I looked at the SDK link that you give me, it does not look more hard than the payflow documentation)))